# Como contar quantos caracteres tem uma string - Swift

Tags: string, swift

Estou tendo algumas dificuldades com coisas simples.
Como eu faço para contar quantas `letras` tem uma variável?

```
let word = wordEasy[0]
for var i = 0; i < word.count ?????
```

Answer (score 5):

Se for **Swift 1**:

```
word.utf16count
```

Se for **Swift 2**:

```
word.characters.count
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Bruno, se a resposta satisfaz a sua dúvida, selecione ela como resposta aceita, para ajudar outras pessoas que possam ter a mesma dúvida no futuro